# Xcode9.4.1: Crash when debugging process as root

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, crash

I'm debugging an Cocoa application which needs high authorized permission.

However, after I changed the item `root` in `Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme...->Run->Debug Process As`, and tried to debug my application, it crashed and  didn't even go to the `int main(int argc, const char * argv[])` function.

I'm using Xcode9.4.1 and MacOS 10.13.6.
I created a new empty Cocoa App project, and tried to debug process as root, which crashed too.

Anybody could help me with this ?

Comment: Looks like it's trying to print "Sandbox registration internal error: %s". Does Switching off App Sandbox help?

Comment: Thanks a lot. but sorry, I'm new. I could not understand what you mean. I will add more info below.

Answer (score -1):

[debug process as root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbuLJ.png)

[crashed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6MnL.png)

the pictures show how I debug process as root and where it crashed.
I debug my application in Administrative staff member

Comment: Is this an answer and is the question answered?